# Replacing float that doesn't work with flex that doesn't work too

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, css-float

I have photo as a background image and it placed right. I also have some list and I want it to be placed left. But it stuck on photo. I used float, but nothing happens. I tried flex but nothing happens too.

[its how the page is looking now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2W26.png)

```css
.section__img1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("../images/section1.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 985px;
  height: 580px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.section__content {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}

.section__content.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="our-services" class="section bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section__img1"></div>
    <div class="section__content">
      <div class="title-block left"><span class="ico-arrow-down"></span> Входящие звонки</div>
      <ul class="section__list">
        <li>Горячая линия</li>
        <li>Виртуальный офис</li>
        <li>Прием заказов</li>
        <li>Консультации по телефону</li>
        <li>Заполнение анкет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's because you absolute position the image and looks like it takes up 985px width so it will most likely be  most of the screen riath than just on the right

Comment: Something to note for future reference is that once you make an item's parent a flexbox, the float property is completely ignored and can be removed. Flexbox doesn't collapse margins either.

Comment: I suggest you do some research or even tutorials on css and html5 positioning. I'd take it a step further and look into bootstrap/responsive styling aka mobile

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```
.section__img1 {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2W26.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 985px;
  height: 580px;
  float:right;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/amit_duhan/pen/KKzWELB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for your container and remove the absolute positioning on your image, then the image div will grow automatically to the same height as your content column:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.section__img1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/300/200") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.section__content {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="our-services" class="section bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section__img1"></div>
    <div class="section__content">
      <div class="title-block left"><span class="ico-arrow-down"></span> Входящие звонки</div>
      <ul class="section__list">
        <li>Горячая линия</li>
        <li>Виртуальный офис</li>
        <li>Прием заказов</li>
        <li>Консультации по телефону</li>
        <li>Заполнение анкет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you, I just need to write "flex-direction: row-reverse" and list moved to empty space and all is looking just fine. Thank you again <3

Answer (score 0):

flex would make it easier:

```css
.container {display:flex;}
.section__img1 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1001/2000/800) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.section__content ,
.section__img1{
flex:1
}
/* switch/reorder  position ? */
.container + .container .section__img1 {
order:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="our-services" class="section bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section__img1"></div>
    <div class="section__content">
      <div class="title-block left"><span class="ico-arrow-down"></span> Входящие звонки</div>
      <ul class="section__list">
        <li>Горячая линия</li>
        <li>Виртуальный офис</li>
        <li>Прием заказов</li>
        <li>Консультации по телефону</li>
        <li>Заполнение анкет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section__img1"></div>
    <div class="section__content">
      <div class="title-block left"><span class="ico-arrow-down"></span> Входящие звонки</div>
      <ul class="section__list">
        <li>Горячая линия</li>
        <li>Виртуальный офис</li>
        <li>Прием заказов</li>
        <li>Консультации по телефону</li>
        <li>Заполнение анкет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set their parent container to a flex display, i.e

`.container { display: flex;  }`

Then the image section:

`.section__img1 { flex-basis: 50%; max-width: 50%; }`

Then, the content section:

`.section__content { flex-basis: 50%; max-width: 50%; }`

This gives you a basic setup to achieve what you are aiming at.

Remove the absolute positions, floatd and work on the .section_img1 height as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to write `flex-direction: row-reverse;` and list moved to empty space and all is looking just fine